# Is execution of `_dl_init` (program initialization) single-threaded in C/C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, thread-safety

I have several C++ source files where some data/callbacks are registered in a map in a header.

```cpp
// foo.h

class Foo final {
public:
    static void Register(...) { ... }

private:
    inline static std::map<...> g_map{};
};

// a.cc, b.cc, etc.

#include "foo.h"

namespace {

struct Init {
    Init() {
        Foo::Register(...);
    }
};

Init g_init{}; // the inversion-of-control trick

}
```

So is it neccessary to use locks to protect the `g_map`?  My intuition is that the execution of `_dl_init` (runtime call that is prior to `main`) is single-threaded, although the order `a.cc`, `b.cc`, ... is unknown, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If non local static variables are initialized before main starts, then they will be initialized in the thread defined in [basic.start.main] (ref. draft n4659 for C++20):

> Executing a program starts a main thread of execution (4.7, 33.3) in which the main function is invoked, and in which variables of static storage duration might be initialized (6.6.2) and destroyed (6.6.4).

But C++ initialization of static variables is not that simple :-(. Same draft says later in [basic.start.dynamic] §4 (emphasize mine):

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static
>   storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly
>   happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the
>   same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. **It is implementation-defined in which threads and
>   at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs**.

My reading is that the standard makes its best to prevent a programmer to make assumptions on the moment of the initialization of a static variable. If the implementation is programmer friendly, it will initialize all non local static variables before main in a single thread - the standard allows it. But unfortunately it would be non portable because the standard does not mandate it.

TL/DR: If you target one single implementation which guarantees to initialize non local static variables before calling main, then you can be sure that this initialization will occur in a single thread. If you are brave, you can try to understand what means *it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized* and how you could use it. And it you only want to have a portable and robust code, accept the fact that dragons are hidden near static initialization and that it could happen in any thread...